# Scrapy Post Request with payload

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a website where I can find the url has a post request with payload parameters as below. I am not sure how to make it to a dictionary in payload and send it in formdata. All the below code comes under `Request with payload` how do I send this in formdata??

```
callCount=1
page=/job.do?uno=auo&internal=1
httpSessionId=724D68422B64D786F28E57EB3EE9D07D.newweb04
scriptSessionId=D0E5AF56ACF10360C6B960329CBB012B883
c0-scriptName=normalAjaxService
c0-methodName=getJobDetailByCustId
c0-id=0
c0-param0=number:1000000157
c0-param1=number:551740849947131
batchId=2
```

This is how I am trying to send the formdata, where I am receiving no response

```
            formdata_2 = {
            'callCount': '1',
            'page': '/job.do?uno=auo&internal=1',
            'httpSessionId': '724D68422B64D786F28E57EB3EE9D07D.newweb04',
            'scriptSessionId': session_id,
            'c0-scriptName': 'normalAjaxService',
            'c0-methodName': 'searchJobs',
            'c0-id': '0',
            'c0-param0=number': '1000000157',
            'c0-param1=string': '',
            'c0-param2=string': '0',
            'c0-param3=string': '0',
            'c0-param4=number': '0',
            'c0-param5=string': 'i88ky1c0',
            'batchId': '0',
        }
```

Comment: So splitting on `?` and `&` characters?

Comment: @figs I didnt get you

Comment: Your second line has 3 equal signs in it.

Comment: @figs   I have updated my question. Can you please check that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure that I understood your question correctly, but if that is the text that you found somewhere on the scraped site, and want to format it into a valid Requests to crawl a new site, you can turn it into a dict as follows:

```
# assume that you got that text inside a variable
scraped = """
callCount=1
page=/job.do?uno=auo&internal=1
httpSessionId=724D68422B64D786F28E57EB3EE9D07D.newweb04
scriptSessionId=D0E5AF56ACF10360C6B960329CBB012B883
c0-scriptName=normalAjaxService
c0-methodName=getJobDetailByCustId
c0-id=0
c0-param0=number:1000000157
c0-param1=number:551740849947131
batchId=2
"""
param_list = [line.split('=', 1) for line in scraped.split('\n')]
formdata = {p[0]:p[1] for p in param_list}
```

Now you have your form data in a dictionary. If the page you are to visit is the `page` parameter from the form data, you can use that and create the apsolute URL with `urlparse` (assuming this is called from inside a callback function, where you have `response` available:

```
page = urlparse.urljoin(response.url, formdata.pop('page'))
```

Now you can follow the link with the appropriate form data:

```
return scrapy.Request(page, formdata=formdata)
```

I hope this answers your question, if not please explain further what you need.

Comment: That was a quick reply. The problem you understood is correct... I have tried the way mentioned by you. But I am unable to find any response in the page after parsing it

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'I am unable to find any response in the page after parsing it'. Please update your question with  relevant parts of your code so I can know what exactly is happening.

Comment: I have provided with the link in the above comment. where you can see the Request Payload headers

Comment: Your update is not enough. You have given no additional information, other than what I already know. Have you passed this dictionary to Request constructor as formdata? What is the return code and body of the Response you get in the callback?

Comment: I get this in response page after passing formdata `
// <script>

//#DWR-REPLY

DWREngine._remoteHandleExceptionWithoutCallId({ type:'java.lang.SecurityException', message:'Session Error' });

// </script>`

Comment: Most likely your `scriptSessionId` is wrong, or some of other fields. Can you paste your spider code?